# "Backshifting" in English

Tags: backshifting

Can anyone please tell me if there is any need to backshift the tense?

Here is the example:

> Yesterday, as a consultant I went to meet my friend Peter who has been found guilty of fraud. He claimed that he ***is/was*** not guilty of any fraud.

Can I use the 'simple present' too?

Answer (score 0):

The [normal rule](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech/reported-speech-indirect-speech) for reported speech requires a backshift in tense, yielding

> *“I’m not guilty!”*       He said he wasn't guilty.

In conversation, the present simple is often used to heighten the topicality or current relevance of the original statement:

> He was telling me all afternoon how he isn't guilty.
>
> Oh, we can't go that way. Linda told me they're closing that road for repairs.

Since your example sentence is simple reported speech, then one would use past simple.

PS: Unless you have a number of friends named Peter who were just convicted of fraud, then you need a comma after "Peter."

Comment: Totally agree with this answer, except that I don't think Peter needs to be between commas. The lack of commas indicates that he has multiple friends, not that he has multiple friends called Peter.

Comment: It's a non-restrictive appositive followed by a non-restrictive relative clause, thus two commas, but since that wasn't part of the original question, I didn't feel the need to go into such detail.

Comment: I actually understand it as a restrictive appositive followed by a non-restrictive relative clause. I think this is preferable to two non-restrictives, because in that case it's ambiguous whether the author has only one friend, or more than one. It could also be understood as a non-restrictive appositive followed by a restrictive relative clause (i.e. "I went to visit my friend [the one found guilty of fraud], who is called Peter").

Comment: Now that I think about it, you're right! Just one comma for the relative. I was having so much fun thinking about jailing Peter between two commas the grammar slipped my mind. Corrected answer accordingly.